# Specify rewrite parameter in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, .htpasswd

In my htaccess I think I must wrong path of RewriteBase.

My server has this structure:

```
/public_html/example
```

and in this example there are all my site so to go on my site I do this url:

```
http://home.com/example
```

But I get 500 internal server because I think I wrong my RewriteBase in my htacess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /example/index.php [L]
</IfModule>


AuthBasicProvider file

AuthUserFile /public_html/festivalmusicasullacqua/.htpasswd.txt
AuthName "Authorization Form Title"
AuthType Basic

#Allow any valid user
require valid-user

#Allow only one user with specified username
require user festival
```

Anyone can help me to correct the code?

Comment: What's in the apache and php error logs?

Comment: I'm in a FTP in a customer client, I access only with ftp, where I find this php error Logs?

Comment: It's defined in the php.ini or in the script itself. It's going to be difficult without ssh access.

Comment: Yes i Know but I can use only FTP. I think the error is RewriteBase variable!

Comment: "I must wrong path of RewriteBase" - FWIW, your `RewriteBase` directive isn't actually doing anything in the code you've posted. (So, it's certainly not the cause of your error.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two parts in your `.htaccess` file: a *rewrite* part, and an *auth* part. I think that the error is not in the *rewrite* part, but in the auth part (you can try commenting it to confirm this hypothesis).

If I am right and the error is in the auth part, the reason is probably that FTP chroots you. Then you only see a *relative* filesystem path.

Thus I doubt that the `AuthUserFile` line has a correct path: you must specify an absolute path.

Comment: Thanks Pierre I correct with your suggest and now it all works. The error is that the path is /home/home/public_html/example